# How to generate import LIBs from OBJS using msbuild

Tags: c++, makefile, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm converting an ancient C/C++ build system from VC98 to VS2017.  We used our own custom makefiles but now I want to use standard VS2017 projects to do the automated builds from the command line.  Bringing in the code is not a problem.  The problem is our old build system and how we built things previously in order to resolve circular dependencies (CD).  *Don't get me started on removing these circular dependencies.  :-)  I know they're bad but it would be a very big task to remove them.*

We had 2 main steps: make shared_lib and make all.  make shared_lib would compile the code into a static or import library (depending on the folder's makefile) and copy the library to a shared LIB folder.  make all would then build any binaries (DLL/EXE) and place in a common BIN folder.  To do a full build we would go to each of the 50+ folders and do make shared_lib in each.  Then we would do make all in each folder.  Example:

- folder A generates import lib A.lib and A.dll, which needs import lib
  B.lib
- folder B generates import lib B.lib and B.dll, which needs import lib A.lib
- We make shared_lib in A and generate import lib A.lib from the OBJs.  We don't need B.lib yet b/c we're only making the import lib
  A.lib.
- We make shared_lib in B and generate import lib B.lib
- make all in A generates A.dll and works b/c we have B.lib in the previous step
- make all in B generates B.dll

I would imagine this can be done in a VS2017 project file but I'm wondering how easily...
I can put in a pre-link build event into folder A project to generate import lib A.lib.  But the main output of project A is A.dll and the only option (that I see) for the output type is DLL.  But then, I cannot finish linking A.dll b/c I don't have B.lib yet.

I created a project that contains the all and shared_lib targets.  And then these targets use the LINK and LIB msbuild tasks.  If it was just that, it wouldn't be too bad.  But I also need to compile these files into OBJs.  That is where I've run into a mess.  Of course, I'm using the CL task but then I have to specify a ton of options.  I specify the Inputs and Outputs and it mostly works.  If I modify a CPP file, only that file is rebuilt, then it generates the LIB, then it generates the DLL - which is what I want.  But the problem is, what if I change a .H file that this CPP file depends on?  It doesn't know to rebuild the CPP file.  It's probably another option (s) that I can specify to CL but it's getting out of hand...

So, it boils down to this: in my test project that mostly works I'm taking full control of the build process.  I don't want this burden.  I want to leave it up to msbuild/VS2017 to figure out which files need rebuilding.  I want to do a "msbuild foo.sln /t:shared_lib" and have msbuild do all the heavy lifting.

I might be able to do this with different projects but that sounds inefficient and harder to automate.  I'm OK with hand crafting a project file but I still want msbuild to be in control (and not me).

Comment: So, I stumbled over $(GenerateImportLib) in Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props.  When set to true, it will generate the import lib before doing the link.  This is specifically to address circular dependencies - which is close to what I need. So, I can generate A.LIB but it will fail to make A.DLL b/c I don't have B.LIB made yet. I want to avoid the error that it cannot make A.DLL.  Any thoughts?  Can I stop the link from happening until I do the make all?

Comment: You should only have to hand craft an MSBuild file that invokes a solution or multiple project files. Don't go deeper and invoke CL and Link yourself. If you are doing the latter, than something is wrong. In which case you need to step back and perhaps make multiple passes. First pass to make static libs. Second pass do something else. And also, you can directly control where everything get's compiled to. Don't copy files around afterwards. That's just plain old innefficient.

Comment: Thanks.  I misspoke in copying to a LIB folder.  Yeah, we do specify the correct options to build the LIB in the appropriate common LIB folder.  And yeah, use of this $(GenerateImportLib) option means we'll need to make multiple passes - which is what we did in the old system. But now the first pass will generate an error.  It's not the end of the world, but I'd like to find a way to avoid the linker error on A.DLL b/c we don't have B.LIB yet (in the first pass).  The 2nd pass will succeed when it builds A.DLL.

Comment: If you painted yourself into a corner, the only way out is to walk across the paint. It's time to fix that mutual dependency you wrote about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's what I did...  I created the A.vcxproj with the $(GenerateImportLib) option. It builds A.lib as part of the build but of course it fails to generate A.dll b/c I'm missing B.lib.  So, I copied A.vcxproj to A_shared_lib.vcxproj (into another folder).  I then tweaked A_shared_lib.vcxproj to stub out the Link task like this:

```
<Target Name="Link">
  <Message Text="Not doing a Link"/>
</Target>
```

So, now the A_shared_lib.vcxproj only builds A.lib.  The Configuration Type is still set to "DynamicLibrary".  And it doesn't generate an error (when it can't find B.lib) because I'm not doing a Link.